# Keeping neo4j updated with production MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, neo4j, migration, etl

I'm investigating the possibility of using neo4j to handle some of the queries of our java web application that simply take too long to run on MSSQL as they require so many joins on large tables, even with indexes implemented.

I am however concerned about the time that it might take to complete the ETL ultimately impacting on how outdated the information may be when queries.

Can someone advise on either a production strategy or toolkit / library that can assist in reading a production sql-server database (using deltas if possible to optimise) and updating a running instance of a neo4j database? I imagine that there will have to be some kind of mapping configuration but the idea is to have this run in an automated manner, updating the neo4j database with one or more sql-server table or view contents.

Answer (score 0):

1. The direct way to connect a MS SQL database to a Neo4j database would be using the **apoc.load.jdbc** procedure.
2. For an initial load you can use Neo4j ETL (https://neo4j.com/blog/rdbms-neo4j-etl-tool/).
3. There is however no way around the fact that some planning and work will be involved if you want to keep two databases in sync (and if the logic involved goes beyond a few simple queries) continiously. You might want to offload a delta every so often (monthly, daily, hourly, ...) into CSV files and load those (with CYPHER syntax determining what needs to be added, removed, changed or connected) with **LOAD CSV**.

Sadly enough there's no such thing as a free lunch.

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: Does the Neo4j ETL support Microsoft SQL Server? From what I see it only has support for MySQL, Postgres & Oracle